# Style last children of last child

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<section></section>

<section id="top">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>   <!-- STYLE THIS -->
        <li>5</li>   <!-- STYLE THIS -->
    </ul>
</section>

<section></section>
```

I have dynamically generated HTML, how do I style the above two things? Apply style to the `section` with `id="top"`, and style the last 2 `list-items` in the last `ul`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#top > ul:last-of-type li:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    background:aqua;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tAaRk/)

Use a combination of selectors - [**`:last-of-type`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type) and [**`:nth-last-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-last-child).

Note - this is [**not fully supported**](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3) by IE8 and down.

Comment: a thing to note these use css3 selectors which are not available in IE below 9.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
#top > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(4),
#top > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(5) {}
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kK5FD/)

Answer (score 1):

```
#top {
    color:red;
}

#top ul:last-of-type li:last-of-type {
    color:green;
}
```